# loop returns despite break

Tags: c#, razor

I am running a loop where I cycle through entries in a database.  Every time the loop runs I compare a user's answer with an value in my database.  The table rows are named answer2, answer3...etc So I concatenate a string: ("answer" + (i)) and use the string with a database.queryValue(string) to put the value from the database into a variable.  (in this case the variable cAltAnsX)

Eventually the loop returns a null value.  I want my loop to terminate before it runs again.  I try to load the queried value into an object and then comparing it to DBNull.Value then try to exit the loop with break;   However I am still comparing the 2 strings.  i.e. uAns.ToLower() == cAns.ToLower().
 My code returns an error since it cannot convert the Null value into a string.
I would like to exit these loops once the query loads a null value (and before the script can attempt to convert it into a string).

I have tried using break and return to end the string, but I still get the same problem.

```
if (!Request.QueryString["uAnswer"].IsEmpty())
{
uAns = Request.QueryString["uAnswer"];

if (uAns.ToLower() == cAns.ToLower())
        {
            anBool = true;
        }
        else                //Should cycle through all answers in alternativeAnswers table
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) 

                {


                                if (uAns.ToLower() == cAltAnsX.ToLower())
                                    {
                                        anBool = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        altAnsXCom = altAnsXCom+1;
                                        string x = altAnsXCom.ToString();
                                        AltCommandTemp = string.Concat(altAns1Com, x, altAns2Com, sQTerm);
                                        cAltAnsX = db.QueryValue(AltCommandTemp);
                                        objcAA = db.Query(AltCommandTemp);

                                       if (objcAA == DBNull.Value)   {break;}
                                        if (cAltAnsX == null) {break;}
                                    }

                    }
            if (anBool != true)
                {
            anBool = false;
                }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see a loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: The loop itself is missing. This looks like the contents of the loop as "currently" posted.

Comment: Your variables really should be named better. It's hard to follow what's happening in your code.

Comment: Could you have a nested loop here? That is a common gotcha of break statements.

Comment: You're going to have to include the full thing. On which line does the exception occur?

Comment: How this is related to Razor if this is some code accessing DB that supposedly come from MVC controller or regular class?

Comment: My guess is you are only checking to see if objcAA is null, but the if statement is using cAltAnsX.

Comment: It's good practice on SO to post all of the relevant code. This question is about a loop so I would expect to see the loop. I would also expect to see the declaration of all of the variables shown. Ideally I should be able to copy and paste code into VS, LINQPad, or https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and be able to at least compile the code. The work you do in presenting your question makes it easier for us to answer and it makes it a quality resource for future readers.

Comment: Sorry all.  This is my second post and I wanted to post a small amount of code to make reading simpler.  I have updated the code to include all of the loops.  I should have also added that I am writing this in razor on webmatrix.  I am not using an MVC controller.
The line of the problem is on:  
if (uAns.ToLower() == cAltAnsX.ToLower())

Answer (score 0):

If this is inside of a function, are you sure you don't want to `return` instead of `break`?

---

Break will only break out of your current scope.  If you have a nested loop/switch case, will only break out of the innermost section.

I would suggest breaking your logic into a separate function or lambda that you can simply short `return` out of.

---

Also, it looks like you may be doing string concatenation for querying a database, which is all-around bad form, as opposed to parameter based queries.

Comment: It seems he has nested if statements but not nested for loops (we can't know without the full code). break is not affected by nested if statements which I think is important to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You say that " the program still crashes since it still compares the Null value to the string in the top part of the script."  I assume this means that is because cAltAnsX is null and you are trying to call cAltAnsX.ToLower()?

In your code you only break if objcAA is null.  I think you need to also check if cAltAnsX is null.

```
if (uAns.ToLower() == cAltAnsX.ToLower())
{
    anBool = true;
}
else  // this reloads the query before subsequent comparison
{
    ...
    cAltAnsX = db.QueryValue(AltCommandTemp);
    objcAA = db.Query(AltCommandTemp);
    if (objcAA == DBNull.Value)   {break;}
    if (cAltAnsX == null)   {break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer.  Part of the problem was that I needed to use

```
(cAltAnsX.Equals(null))
```

or

```
(DBNull.Value.Equals(objcAA))
```

Rather than

```
(string == null) or (object == DBNull.Value)
```

If anyone can educate me regarding the difference between these two strategies I would be grateful.
Then I got round the problem by putting these conditions in an if loop.
I.e.

```
 if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(objcAA))
{
   //do stuff
}
```